# Confusion about Cucumber Page Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I've just started using cucumber to test my Rails apps. I've been very successful blindly following the many good examples.

```
Given /^I visit (.*) web page$/ do |page|
  visit page
  page.should have_text("some text")
end
```

Obviously, the call to `visit` populates the `page` object. And I have surmised that multiple calls to `visit`, or `click_link`, will re-fill the `page` object. But I'd like a better idea of where and when the `page` object is instantiated and its scope. Is it global or do I have to set `@page= page` after I call `visit`?

I've looked through the capybara source too and really don't have a good feel for the `page` object.   Where can I find good documentation?

Edit:  Even more confusion

It appears that I should be using `have_content` instead of `have_text`.  My confusion today is that:

```
page.should have_content("this text does not exist on the page")
```

always passes.  I don't understand why this does not fail?

Comment: `page.should have_content("absent")` should fail as you say. Have you done something to your `page` elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been solved.  Capybara fails silently if you are using ruby 1.8.7 (which is what I am using on my mac)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cukes/B3UbbyG5k6s